# Impala does not recognize partition where partition value has an embedded quote

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, impala, parquet

I have a spark statement like so:

```
df.partitionBy("columnA","columnB").parquet("output_folder")
```

One of the values for columnA has an embedded single quote, like so:
"Jack's Tavern"

The output folder it generates for rows containing this value for columnA has the encoding of %27A instead of the quote like this:

```
output_folder/columnA=Jack%27As Tavern
```

I have an impala external table sitting on top of output_folder. Impala does not show this particular partition when I do a show partition.

How do I make impala recognize this partition?

Comment: `%27` is a standard [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for `'`. What else would you expect?

Comment: I agree, it is expected, but my requirement is that the folder name should appear "as is " without the encoding. Are you saying it is impossible?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is impossible. Just any other URI representation wouldn't be exactly valid. And to be honest I simply don't see a problem here. It is a well defined encoding, there is no loss of information.

Comment: I should have stated the actual problem. I have an impala table sitting on top and impala does not recognize the partition as it should. If I do a show partitions, I do not see this value.

Comment: Yes, it makes more sense now. You should edit your question to include all relevant information and tag it correctly.